# GWT CellTable and SimplePager issue

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am using a `CellTable<Contact>` in my GWT 2.4 project. Everything worked perfectly, so I decided to add paging to the table by using a `SimplePager`. The `CellTable` now displays the correct number of entries (page size), but all the pager buttons are disabled.

I am doing the following:

```
...
@UiField(provided=true) CellTable<Contact> contactsTable = new CellTable<Contact>();
@UiField SimplePager pager;

private TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn;
private TextColumn<Contact> surnameColumn;

public ViewContactsViewImplDesktop() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    initTable();
}

@Override
public final void updateContactList(final ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    contactsTable.setRowCount(contacts.size());

    final ListDataProvider<Contact> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Contact>();

    List<Contact> list = dataProvider.getList();

        for (final Contact c : contacts) {
            list.add(c);
        }

        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(contactsTable);

        pager = new SimplePager();
        pager.setDisplay(contactsTable);
        pager.setPageSize(3);

        ListHandler<Contact> nameColumnSorter = new ListHandler<Contact>(list);
        ListHandler<Contact> surnameColumnSorter = new ListHandler<Contact>(list);

        nameColumnSorter.setComparator(nameColumn, new Comparator<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
                return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());
            }
        });

        surnameColumnSorter.setComparator(surnameColumn, new Comparator<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
                return c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname());
            }
        });

        contactsTable.addColumnSortHandler(nameColumnSorter);
        contactsTable.addColumnSortHandler(surnameColumnSorter);
        contactsTable.getColumnSortList().push(nameColumn);
    }

    private void initTable() {
        nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
            @Override
                public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                    return contact.getName();
                }
            };

            surnameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
                @Override
                public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                    return contact.getSurname();
                }
            };

            nameColumn.setSortable(true);
            surnameColumn.setSortable(true);

            contactsTable.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
            contactsTable.addColumn(surnameColumn, "Surname");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Your pager is created by UiBinder but the field is overwritten in the updateContactList method (no need to, that one instance is fine).  
2) `dataProvider.getList().addAll(contacts)`  
3) Have you tried not setting the page size and/or not setting the table's row count manually?

Comment: @Flo - What a legend! Re-post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Ah, glad to be of help. Was struggling with the formatting... Will repost as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not setting the page size and/or not setting the table's row count manually could do the trick, as hinted in my comment.
I'd love to provide a concise code sample but do not have access to any code using cell widgets right now.